# Send file over cURL - php

Tags: php

I need to send a file over cURL to a server, and the server require the following from the file:

- filename
- checkSum
- mimeType
- size

I have tried the following methods:

1. Using @ and the full path to the file
2. file-get-contents
3. Just the fullpath
4. new CURLFile, with and without the extra parameters

   ```
   $mime = mime_content_type($file); 
   $info = pathinfo($file); 
   $name = $info['basename']; 
   $output = new CURLFile($file, $mime, $name);
   ```
5. curl_file_create
6. curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, true);

When I use @, it just asks for the extra details mentioned above. When I use new CURLFile and curl_file_create the browser just times out.

But when I use it directly in bash, like this:

```
curl -X POST -F 'file=@dog.jpg' -F 'category=video' -F 'language=English' -F 
'subject_name= Accounting' -F 'studyYear=ALL' -F 'title=Test resources 3' -F 
'description=This is a test 3' http://127.0.0.1:5000/postfile -u root -p
```

Then it works flawlessly. I am not sure what I should do in php.

**Edit**

This is the error I get when cURL to the server:

```
{"query":"add a new resource","doc":"resource-2db43d6f","info":"Schema validation failed","_xerror":true,"message":"child \"filename\" fails because [\"filename\" is required]. child \"checkSum\" fails because [\"checkSum\" is required]. child \"mimeType\" fails because [\"mimeType\" is required]. child \"size\" fails because [\"size\" is required]","isJoi":true,"name":"ValidationError","details":[{"message":"\"filename\" is required","path":"filename","type":"any.required","context":{"key":"filename"}},{"message":"\"checkSum\" is required","path":"checkSum","type":"any.required","context":{"key":"checkSum"}},{"message":"\"mimeType\" is required","path":"mimeType","type":"any.required","context":{"key":"mimeType"}},{"message":"\"size\" is required","path":"size","type":"any.required","context":{"key":"size"}}],"_object":{"_id":"resource-2db43d6f","owner":1,"created":1541769732,"private":false,"feedback":false,"category":"video","language":"English","studyYear":"ALL","title":"testing code","description":"This is a test","subject":0},"reqPath":"POST /api/1.0/resources/","detail":"child \"filename\" fails because [\"filename\" is required]. child \"checkSum\" fails because [\"checkSum\" is required]. child \"mimeType\" fails because [\"mimeType\" is required]. child \"size\" fails because [\"size\" is required]","person":"user"}`
```

So those fields must be included in the file itself. And not as extra.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by “checksum”. The cURL command you have shown does not seem to perform any extra calculations in that regard, so what you actually mean by that is unclear.

Comment: Well the thing is, I don't even have to specify the mimeType and the Size of the file when using it in bash. but when I do a normal cURL with php the server return that I need to include those parameters. So checksum I am not even sure, but the error says that it is required.

Comment: That still doesn’t explain what that checksum is supposed to be in the first place. Do you have access to this server, so that you could log what exactly it receives in both cases? Otherwise, set up your own script to do that, and then send a request to it both ways (cURL CLI, your attempt with PHP), and check what the relevant differences might be.

Comment: Check my edit above

Answer (score 0):

I have found this example doing a quick search in Google.

Keywords used for the search are: *send file over cURL in php*

> The following code makes a request to http://example.com/, uploads the
>   file example.txt, and outputs the response.

```
// initialise the curl request
$request = curl_init('http://example.com/');

// send a file
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt(
    $request,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
    array(
      'file' => '@' . realpath('example.txt')
    ));

// output the response
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
echo curl_exec($request);

// close the session
curl_close($request);
```

Credits:

Kate Morley
http://code.iamkate.com/php/sending-files-using-curl/

Comment: Did that as well. Number 1 in my list.